# Set CheckBox enabled if togglebutton is checked

Tags: android, checkbox, android-togglebutton

I created a Togglebutton for my push notification service (if the button is checked, notifications will be reveived). I also want, that when I check the button, a checkbox is checkbox. If the button isn't check, the checkbox should disabled.

I used that code, but it do not work. Only when the togglebutton is off, the checkbox is disabled. But it do not work otherwise.

```
        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toogleNotifications);

    toggle.setChecked(Pushbots.sharedInstance().isNotificationEnabled());
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Pushbots.sharedInstance().toggleNotifications(isChecked);
            chicken.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    if (toggle.isChecked()) {
        chicken.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what are you trying to implement but to enable/disable the `checkbox` on `toggle` change, you should do it like that:

```
 toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Pushbots.sharedInstance().toggleNotifications(isChecked);
            chicken.setEnabled(isChecked);
        }
    });
```

and you don't need this part:

```
    if (toggle.isChecked()) {
        chicken.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chicken.setEnabled(false);
```

Should be

```
chicken.setEnabled(isChecked);
```

While at it,

```
if (toggle.isChecked())
 { chicken.setEnabled(true);}
```

Should be a plain

```
chicken.setEnabled(toggle.isChecked());
```